# Quality loss switching from sculpt mode to object mode

Tags: vertices, sculpting, sculpt, smooth

I'm not experienced in sculpting and I often run in troubles I'm sure I could avoid easily so it's kinda frustrating haha. Anyway, yesterday I had a problem I never had before, maybe it is because of dynotopo. When switching from sculpt mode to object mode, the mesh looks different as if some vertices were missing (the mesh has no modifiers)

[image]

[image]

Thanks for reading, hope your day is good

Comment: I think it’s a normals problem, though I do not know if/how Auto-smooth could be enabled, but turn off while sculpting.

Comment: @TheLabCat thanks for answering ! Indeed when I don't enable auto smooth, I don't have this problem. Now I know how to avoid this issue even if it is annoying. Thanks !

Comment: Hello, does anyone have anything to add? I ran into this problem again even though I don't use the auto smooth

Comment: I’m the only one that got notified ‘cause I’m the only one that commented. But whatever. As long as no answers have been posted to the question, it will remain in the unanswered section.

Comment: @TheLabCat Okay I see, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Object Context Menu (right mouse click) use "Shade Smooth" instead of "Shade Auto Smooth".
It should help.